# Flash AS3 Printing

Tags: flash, printing

Is it possible to remove the default print window that Windows opens when you print using the print class in Flash?

Best Regards
Luben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I solved it. Simply configure firefox to print silent.
Then Like Neoraptor said use ExternalInterface.
Then Finally JS for the variables.

Thanks Neoraptor!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware no.

Flash is quite a closed(protected) platform.

It might be able to be bypassed with Javascript and ExternalInterface.

Comment: Ok so im trying to print with JavaScript.
I use the window.print() function but it still brings up a dialog window? Are there any other suggestions?

Comment: I found this code,
<html>
<head>
<title>Print Test</title>
<script>
      function Print()
         {
          if (document.all) 
             {
               WebBrowser1.ExecWB(6, 6) //use 6, 1 to prompt the print dialog or 6, 6 to omit it; 
                WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";
             }
         else
            {
             window.print();
             }
         }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <object ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH="0" HEIGHT="0" 
    CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"> 
    </object>
 <A HREF="#" onClick="Print()">Print this page</a>
</body>
</htm

Comment: Been trying it in IE but it still doesnt work. And the Information bar displays "An add-on for this site failed to run"...
Appreciate any help.

Comment: not an expert on th esubject, start searching on the net for that :)